# How do I include a lot of log file data in my question?

Tags: discussion, external-links

What's the process for including log file data in a question?  I'd like to link to it separately, so it doesn't distract from the main question.  Does SO provide some sort of external file reference, or do I have to post the file somewhere else and link to it?

Comment: Duplicate on the über–Meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215981/how-to-post-large-log-results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with external links is that if you don't maintain it, your question will become obsolete in time.

You might just need to take your logs and cut some data to just show what's relevant, and then copy that in your question.

Comment: Yeah, which is why I'm wondering if SO provides some sort of file-upload where I could link to a file within the site, however external to the question.

Comment: not that I know of or ever heard about. I do think "massaging" your log to make them "minimal" to understand your question is what it'll be all about in your case

Answer (score 4):

> Does SO provide some sort of external file reference, or do I have to post the file somewhere else and link to it?

The answer is "No" to both parts.

Stack Overflow does not have a file hosting service (apart from an agreement with imgur for image files).

Next, you *should not* link the entire log file from your question. (This would still be true even if there was a Stack Overflow file service.) If it's too much information to be copy-pasted into the question itself, then you should trim it until the *relevant parts* do fit.

Figuring out which parts are relevant is part of the work you need to do before asking a question, just as you're expected to create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for specific code that's acting incorrectly.

Comment: I should say that I agree completely with [Julldar's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271044/603977) but I thought that it should be worded more strongly.

Comment: 100% with you. I wasn't so sure about part 1 of the question (even if I had a hunch it was "no"), so I didn't want to phrase it too strongly.